# Download huge number of files in chunks

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, download

I'm trying to download a bunch (some thousands) of files using Python Selenium in Firefox by giving an input list. I'm downloading successfully.

Since there are thousands of files I want to download, I was wondering if you could suggest a way to start downloading 10 files, wait until they are completed and start next 10. How can I do that?

I tried `fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", True)` to close the browser after download finishes. But it doesn't close.

Comment: For just downloading files, Selenium is the exact WRONG tool. Have a look at something like https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: @SiKing Oh I forgot to mention that the website has some limitations and it wouldn't allow me download using urllib/wget/mechanize/anything of that kind. I'd really appreciate if you could remove your downvote since I haven't blindly posted the question and I know what I'm doing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [`rq`](http://python-rq.org/), [`Celery`](http://www.celeryproject.org) or any other libraries which makes producing & consuming of tasks much easier.

By using those libraries, you can start downloading first 10 files. Immediately after completing those files, next files will start downloading automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it and will let you know.